# ¿Còmo convertir correctamente una fecha con date pipe?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date, pipe

Estoy utilizando un pipe para convertir una hora que recibo de un objeto, pero estoy recibien el siguiente error cuando llamo el evento click:

En la imagen cuando carga la primera vez se ve bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando llamo al evento click sucede lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi HTML donde formateo la hora usando un date pipe

```html
<swiper class="TimeContainer" [config]='swiperConfig' (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" (slideChange)="onSlideChange()">
  <ng-template swiperSlide class="SwiperItem text-center" *ngFor="let slot of slots; let i = index">

    <button *ngIf="selectedTime == slot.start" mat-stroked-button>{{slot.start}}
                                                </button>
    <button *ngIf="selectedTime != slot.start" mat-flat-button color='primary' class="SelectedTime" (click)="setTime(slot.start)" [disabled]="!slot.available || getHoursPased(slot.start)">{{slot.start | date: 'shortTime'}}
                                                </button>

  </ng-template>
</swiper>
```

Y este es el evento click

//Evento click que se llama cuando se selecciona una hora

```
selectedTime: any;
 setTime(start: any) {
    this.selectedTime = start;
    console.log('select time', start);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te faltaría agregar el `pipe` también en esta línea

```
<button *ngIf="selectedTime == slot.start" mat-stroked-button>{{slot.start | date: 'shortTime'}}
```

Comment: Hola! Muchísimas gracias por responderme, fijate que no me habia fijado, solo que estoy recibiendo el siguiente error: "ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Invalid Date" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'" Entiendo que alli la conversión se ha realizado mal, que no se puede convertir un string a un dateTime, ¿cuál sería la mejor forma de convertir a DateTime? Es decir, al usuario se le muestra el formato "shortTime" pero por detrás cuando sucede el evento click debo convertir a DateTime porque es ese el formato que enviaré a la API. Se que aqui es dificil darme entender, gracia